# QObject.moveToThread(thread) if thread is a child of that object

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, qthread, qobject

I wanted to create `QObject` (*object*) with the child `QThread` (*thread*) with that *object* as parent (for keeping *thread* alive while *object* is alive) and make `object.moveToThread(thread)` but signal to start the *thread* isn't working in this case.

Simply:

1. *object* owns *thread*
2. *object* moves to *thread*
3. signal starting *thread* isn't working

**What's going on?**

Comment: Can you show the connect() statement? Also, have you tried if it returns true?

Comment: @Tim Meyer, *"Also, have you tried if it returns true?"* Yes, it returns true. If I set other `QObject` as parent to thread - it's okay and all works.

Comment: @Tim Meyer, I made function (`object.start()`) that emits `started()` signal from *object* and also I connected *object*'s `started()` signal to `start()` slot of the *thread*. And I starting thread with calling `object.start()` function. Emitting `object.started()` signal is okay in all cases but `thread` starts only if he is child of **another** `QObject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]: Throwing away my initial answer due to the comments

Maybe do it like the following:

1. Create the Object
2. Create the Thread, but don't assign a parent to it
3. Connect the Thread's finished() signal to its deleteLater() slot as usual
4. Connect the Object's deleted() signal to the thread's stop() slot

Then, when you delete the Object, it will emit deleted() which will stop the thread. The thread will emit finished() which will call its deleteLater() slot.

Comment: @Tym Meyer, *"TestObject owns the thread "* - I don't know C++ and can't check this code but I understand some parts of your code above. Maybe I wrong but when we create thread that must be owned by some Obj, we make QThread(parent = Obj) and then thread is owned by the Obj. Or if we directly call thread.setParent(Obj) - it's the same. In your case object isn't owns thread but have the thread as an argument of itself. I already thought about it and I don't need this behavior.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked your pyqt tag, sorry. In fact it doesn't work any longer when I set the parent. In Qt for C++ every QObject may have a parent, but it does not have to. Is this different for PyQt?

Comment: No, it makes no sense. But I need to set parent to keep `QObject` as container for thread(s) with cool interface `th = container.findChild(QThread, name = "awesom_thread_56")` and when I call `thread.setParent(0)`, then thread automatically deletes from container by destructor maybe. Or if I simply delete thread - it deletes from parent `QObject`'s child. If there are no references to thread then it's completely deletes. It's also useful for memory management to make connection of thread's `finished()` signal with thread's `deleteLater` slot. Then the magic with hierarchycal objects can happen

Comment: @Tym Meyer, "The thread will emit finished() which will call its deleteLater() slot." Great! I made another object as member of initial object and set it as parent to thread. And now applying your suggestion. Thanks. But are you sure that when object deleted the thread have time to stop itself before it's deletion?

Comment: @Tym Meyer, But I still think why we can't start thread that is child of object moved to that thread... That was the basic question.

Comment: There will only be a problem if you subclassed QThread and access the object from the thread

Comment: Yes you can't start a thread which is a child of the object it uses. If anything, the object should be a child of the thread

Comment: Okay, I think there is limitation of Qt. But you helped me with right terminating thread when parent object deletes. Just connect object's `destroyed()` signal with `terminate()` or `quit()` or `exit()` slot of thread. Note that when thread is destroying - `thread.wait()` called automatically, so that you don't care about it and unparenting it =) Think that this thread of discussion may be closed until someone comes and teels us about my basic question and why it comes that way. Thank you and good luck with your... whatever you're doing =) P.S. I'll mark your answer as accepted anyway.